# Count recurrences in a collection and merge aggregation result to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to count the recurrences of a value in the collection A, so I do

```
db.collectionA.aggregate( [ { $group : { name : "$name", count :{$sum: 1 } } } ] )
```

And have something like

```
{
  "name": "Bruce",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "_id": "Alfred",
  "count": 3
}
```

Then I need to get this result and populate a field of the collection B, I imagine something like a forEach but don't know how to implement

```
db.collectionB.findAndModify({query: {"name":forEach of the pervious result},
update:{"nameRecurrences": value of the count}})
```

Comment: So you wanted to update `collection B`'s `nameRecurrences` field with `count` result based on `name` field match ? What is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: Exactly! The version is 3.6.16

Comment: Which MongoDB driver are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your aggregation pipeline :

```
db.collectionA.aggregate( [ 
      { $group : { _id : '$name', name : {$first : "$name"}, nameRecurrences :{$sum: 1 } } }, // renamed field `nameRecurrences` to match with field name in `collection-B`
      {$project : {_id : 0}} ] ) // Removing _id to avoid conflicts on merge
```

On MongoDB version >= `4.2` you can use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#merge-aggregation) aggregation operator to merge result of aggregation pipeline on one collection to another collection :

Just add below stage as last stage of aggregation pipeline :

```
{$merge : { into: { db: "dbName", coll: "collectionB" }, on: "name", whenNotMatched: "discard"}} // Remember to create unique index on `name` field on `collectionB`
```

Since you're using MongoDB version `3.6.16` :

If the collection has to be created now then you can use `$out`, but if it's an existing collection with lot of fields in each document apart from just `name & nameRecurrences` then you can try this in code :

Since you've different filters and their respective update part, then you can take advantage of [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#db-collection-bulkwrite) to update multiple documents :

```
let bulkArr = []

for (const i of aggregationResult){
    bulkArr.push( { updateOne : {
        "filter" : { "name" : i.name },
        "update" : { $set : { "nameRecurrences" : i.nameRecurrences } }
     } })
}

db.collectionB.bulkWrite(bulkArr)
```

Comment: Hey my friend, really appreciate your help. I was trying to do this with only a mongo script and since I wasnt able, I had made a python script like yours. Since I used the same logic, I'll make your response the correct one. Thanks